# Match date in column and work backwards to find first prior occurrence of value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula that matches a name in column 1 and then date in a dynamically selected column and then work backwards to find the date of the first prior occurrence of a specific value (in this instance RNR) from that date.

**Data Table:**

| Name | 01/07/2021 | 02/07/2021 | 03/07/2021 | 04/07/2021 | 05/07/2021 | 06/07/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | RNR | RNR | RNR | DS | DS | DS |
| Joe | RNR | DS | DS | DS | DS | DS |

For example, in the following table, if I specify Bob and 05/07/2021, then working backwards the first prior occurrence of RNR is 03/07/2021. For Joe it would be 01/07/2021.

| Name | Date | Date of last RNR occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 05/07/2021 | ??? *(expected result is **03/07/2021**)* |
| Joe | 04/07/2021 | ??? *(expected result is **01/07/2021**)* |

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you've been trying, presumably you have efforts you could post? Perhaps MINIFS.

Comment: What version of excel do you have? Do you have Excel365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=MAXIFS($1:$1,2:2,"RNR",$1:$1,"<"&B7)` would work and copy down. This works if the names listed are in the same order as your data. Otherwise combine it with INDEX: `=MAXIFS($1:$1,INDEX($1:$3,MATCH(A7,A1:A3,0),),"RNR",$1:$1,"<"&B7)`

Comment: Appreciate the answer, this worked as expected too

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=MAX(($B$2:$G$3="RNR")*($A$2:$A$3=A7)*($B$1:$G$1))
```

You may need array entry for non 365 version of excel. Array entry means confirm formula to cell by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]